Particle filter help needed
I am currently trying to implement a partial filter in the ros, RVis and gazebo environment. Currently I have implemented a motion model and a sensor model to try to complete the assignment and am currently a little bit stuck. When I am running the code I am finding that I am able to load and calculate some particles for them to show up in the RVis environment. I know the motion model is working because as the robot moves forward 3 units all of the particles move forward 3 units but all in the direction they were randomly started in. I am having trouble making the particles change direction to try to locate the robot leading me to believe the sensor model is not working. Below is a link to most of my files for the project. The main one I am coding the particle filter in is the particle-filter-2.py file. If you don't mind taking a look at my code to help me fix this problem that would be amazing! Thanks in advance!
https://github.com/BennettSpitz51/particle-filter.git
